# Listview adding to the same line

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an android app that lists connected clients in a listview, but whenever someone connects, it just adds them to the same line, this is the code I use to add connected client. I am new to listview, and not sure how to do this properly, I looked at the android docs but hard to say what needs to be used. If anyone can help me out that would be great.

```
remoteip += socket.getInetAddress();

ArrayList<String> addclientlist = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainserverActivity.this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, addclientlist);

addclientlist.add(remoteip);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listview.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use this constructor

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainserverActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addclientlist);
```

Also no need to set adapter always just set it once and each time you have to add new item to adapter you can use either of these as in java Array objects are pass by reference, and then call notifydatasetchanged

```
adapter.add(remoteip);
//or addclientlist.add(remoteip);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // Dont forget this
```

Comment: it seems to work but when second client connects it inputs the first ip address (from line one) into the second item list like this /firstipaddress/secondipaddress and if third item connects it will be /firstipaddress/secondipaddress/thirdipaddress
EDIT; nevermind I figured it out in remoteip += socket.getInetAddress I had to remove + to make it = and were all good.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the adapter initialization list, which is futile.

Instead - update the actual adapter:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainserverActivity.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, addclientlist);
listview.setAdapter(adapter)
...........

adapter.add(remoteip); // <----- instead of addclientlist.add()
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I appreciate it, but unfortunately I still get the same results. still adding to the same line.